# Mongoose/Express population issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern, mongoose-populate

Here are my schemas:

1.The Records schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const RecordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Title: { type: String, required: true },
    postedby: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
    Author: { type: String, required: true },
    ISBN: { type: String, required: true },
    Review: { type: String },
    SelectedFile: { type: String },
    Likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
module.exports = Records = mongoose.model('record', RecordsSchema, 'record');
```

Here is the The user Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    records: [{
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'record'
    }],
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now(), immutable: true }
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user');
```

The express route for getting a record:

```
router.get('/postedby/', (req, res) => {
    Records.findOne()
        .populate('postedby')
        .exec()
        .then(post => {
            if (!post) {
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Add Posts' });
            }
            else return res.json(post);
        }).catch(err => console.error(err))
});
```

Result of the route:

```
{
    "postedby": [],
    "Likes": 0,
    "_id": "5fed8c12a4fb2c1e98ef09f6",
    "Title": "New Age",
    "Author": "Situma Prisco",
    "ISBN": "23422",
    "SelectedFile": "",
    "Review": "",
    "Date": "2020-12-31T08:30:10.321Z",
    "__v": 0
},
```

I'm getting a blank Array on the populated user field(posteddby) .
Please help, What am I doing wrong? And yes, i do have a User Logged in

Comment: With "Records.findByID()" you get the same?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented your code and Schemas, It's work for me, if you stored data correctly in the database, every things will be ok...

note :

please use `find({})` instead of `findOne()` if data is not displayed again for postedby key, Other issues need to be addressed like mongoose version and ..., because your code and schemas is correct

it's result for me with `find({})`:

```
[
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6bc0bd9e7437184b83f76",
                    "5ff6bc23d9e7437184b83f78",
                    "5ff6bc85f1045a4f102bc0cd",
                    "5ff6bca1f1045a4f102bc0ce",
                    "5ff6bca5f1045a4f102bc0cf",
                    "5ff6bcb3f1045a4f102bc0d0",
                    "5ff6bcc7f1045a4f102bc0d1"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6b81df463322abc7406ec",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T07:28:15.654Z",
                "email": "a@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$wJVDysQxbjuRve.hYn/lbO0rskhwj6y8lwDuEWpCwHeNT/V2mybs.",
                "__v": 7
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T07:47:11.610Z",
        "_id": "5ff6bca1f1045a4f102bc0ce",
        "Title": "farsi",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6bc0bd9e7437184b83f76",
                    "5ff6bc23d9e7437184b83f78",
                    "5ff6bc85f1045a4f102bc0cd",
                    "5ff6bca1f1045a4f102bc0ce",
                    "5ff6bca5f1045a4f102bc0cf",
                    "5ff6bcb3f1045a4f102bc0d0",
                    "5ff6bcc7f1045a4f102bc0d1"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6b81df463322abc7406ec",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T07:28:15.654Z",
                "email": "a@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$wJVDysQxbjuRve.hYn/lbO0rskhwj6y8lwDuEWpCwHeNT/V2mybs.",
                "__v": 7
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T07:47:11.610Z",
        "_id": "5ff6bca5f1045a4f102bc0cf",
        "Title": "farsi",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6bc0bd9e7437184b83f76",
                    "5ff6bc23d9e7437184b83f78",
                    "5ff6bc85f1045a4f102bc0cd",
                    "5ff6bca1f1045a4f102bc0ce",
                    "5ff6bca5f1045a4f102bc0cf",
                    "5ff6bcb3f1045a4f102bc0d0",
                    "5ff6bcc7f1045a4f102bc0d1"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6b81df463322abc7406ec",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T07:28:15.654Z",
                "email": "a@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$wJVDysQxbjuRve.hYn/lbO0rskhwj6y8lwDuEWpCwHeNT/V2mybs.",
                "__v": 7
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T07:47:11.610Z",
        "_id": "5ff6bcb3f1045a4f102bc0d0",
        "Title": "riyazi",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6bc0bd9e7437184b83f76",
                    "5ff6bc23d9e7437184b83f78",
                    "5ff6bc85f1045a4f102bc0cd",
                    "5ff6bca1f1045a4f102bc0ce",
                    "5ff6bca5f1045a4f102bc0cf",
                    "5ff6bcb3f1045a4f102bc0d0",
                    "5ff6bcc7f1045a4f102bc0d1"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6b81df463322abc7406ec",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T07:28:15.654Z",
                "email": "a@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$wJVDysQxbjuRve.hYn/lbO0rskhwj6y8lwDuEWpCwHeNT/V2mybs.",
                "__v": 7
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T07:47:11.610Z",
        "_id": "5ff6bcc7f1045a4f102bc0d1",
        "Title": "zaban",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6c275964d062f045e93d3",
                    "5ff6c283964d062f045e93d5"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6c253964d062f045e93d2",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T08:01:21.499Z",
                "email": "b@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$jmHUrTSPwjaVd0VEIpsGauExHNSukHRyWWiJt4UlEgeWLBo8GPDH.",
                "__v": 2
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T08:01:21.990Z",
        "_id": "5ff6c275964d062f045e93d3",
        "Title": "zaban",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "postedby": [
            {
                "records": [
                    "5ff6c275964d062f045e93d3",
                    "5ff6c283964d062f045e93d5"
                ],
                "_id": "5ff6c253964d062f045e93d2",
                "Date": "2021-01-07T08:01:21.499Z",
                "email": "b@test.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$jmHUrTSPwjaVd0VEIpsGauExHNSukHRyWWiJt4UlEgeWLBo8GPDH.",
                "__v": 2
            }
        ],
        "Likes": 1,
        "Date": "2021-01-07T08:01:21.990Z",
        "_id": "5ff6c283964d062f045e93d5",
        "Title": "tttt",
        "Author": "javid1",
        "ISBN": "1",
        "Review": "1",
        "SelectedFile": "1",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: it doesn't change the results.

Comment: I implemented your code and Schemas, It's work for me, The data is stored correctly in the database?

Comment: Mohammad, thank-you so much for taking time to respond to this. However,  I'm still getting blank arrays.... What else might I be not looking at?

Comment: I think you have to  reset  DB, After removing all collections, and storing your data again, the relations managed by mongoose's populate() will work.